# QListWidgetItem is not drawn correctly

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, qt, qlistwidget

I build up a ruse of CustomWidgets in a QListWidget. So far, it works well.
A problem occurs when I move the vertical scroll bar downwards and want to display items that were not previously visible.
Then they are inserted as transparent rectangles, I can click them and respond to the clicks, but they are not drawn. They stay transparent!

I insert a picture to get a rough idea of the problem:
[image]

In my QListWidget I try to repaint it, but it doesn't work:

```
QListWidget::verticalScrollbarValueChanged(value);
auto item = this->itemAt(QPoint(24, value));
if (!item)
{
    return;
}

auto widget = this->itemWidget(item);
if (!widget)
{
    return;
}

//    widget->resize(widget->size());
//    widget->repaint();
widget->update();
```

What can I do? Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**
According to the request of Martin, I insert here a routine, which shows the addition of items:

```
void ListControl::AddCustomWidget(QWidget* customWidget, const QSize& size, bool forceSize)
{
    if (forceSize)
    {
        customWidget->adjustSize();
    }

    auto displaySize = customWidget->size();
    auto width = size.width();
    auto height = size.height();

    auto item = new QListWidgetItem(this);
    this->addItem(item);

    if (width >= 0)
    {
        displaySize.setWidth(width);
    }
    else
    {
        displaySize.setWidth(displaySize.width() - (this->verticalScrollBar()->width() + this->rightSpace));
    }

    if (height >= 0)
    {
        displaySize.setHeight(height);
    }

    item->setSizeHint(displaySize);
    this->setItemWidget(item, customWidget);
}
```

Comment: Does this only happen on iphone or on desktop, too? Could you please provide a minimal compilable example?

Comment: The structure is quite complex. I could possibly introduce the items-addition here. Because that (I think) is a key moment

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adjusting `displaySize` the way you're doing it? Did you debug the function and look into what displaySize actually becomes? (E.g. if width would be <= 0, that might lead to the widget not being visible.)

Comment: item-> setSizeHint is a critical indication. If this is not done correctly, there are likely to be problems. The method I use gives me the best results. I've checked DisplaySize, it's always correct. In addition, if I mark the item, a blue marker is drawn, but the peculiar content is not displayed.